MySQL Where vs INNER JOIN performance
I'd like to understand why the following 2 queries that select duplicates from the companies table have different execution times. The second query with the JOIN is executed much faster.
The query is executed on:

a companies table with ~200k records
of which there are 195k unique name column values (each query returns ~1500 results, namely the duplicates)
there is a nameindex index on the name column

WHERE (0.31142875 s):
SELECT *
FROM `companies`
WHERE `name` IN (
    SELECT `name`
    FROM `companies`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 1
);

JOIN (0.07034850 s):
SELECT *
FROM `companies`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `name`
    FROM `companies`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 1
) AS `duplicate_names` ON `companies`.`name` = `duplicate_names`.`name`;  

Note that the subqueries are exactly the same. Why is it that in this specific setup the second query is faster?
The output from EXPLAIN is:
WHERE query:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
PRIMARY
companies
NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
195258
100.00
Using where


2
SUBQUERY
companies
NULL
index
nameindex
nameindex
1022
NULL
195258
100.00
Using index



JOIN query:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
PRIMARY

NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
195258
100.00
NULL


1
PRIMARY
companies
NULL
ref
nameindex
nameindex
1022
duplicate_names.name
1
100.00
NULL


2
DERIVED
companies
NULL
index
nameindex
nameindex
1022
NULL
195258
100.00
Using index




The poor performance is due to lack of index use on PRIMARY companies table in first query. It won't even let you force the index use, unless the index is covering for the outer query.

WHERE IN is in most cases the worst varinant - use INNER JOIN or WHERE NOT EXISTS (depends on the data statistic).

Why is it that in this specific setup the second query is faster? WHERE IN can either scan all rows gathered within the subquery or hiddenly index them - the sorting which is used while this subquery processing is lost out of the subquery. INNER JOIN remembers about the rowset is sorted and uses something similar to the sorted lists merge. PS. This is not absolutely correct but this is near.

@Akina is there any way to make the WHERE variant behave as in the second one? Adding a manual ORDER BY name to the subquery does nothing (I guess that is expected since I never heard of MySQL being able to infer ordering from that). Maybe forcing an index? I think the sorted lists merge is indeed applied only in the JOIN ON case and not in the WHERE IN case.

Adding a manual ORDER BY name to the subquery does nothing The phrase "the sorting which is used while this subquery processing is lost out of the subquery" means both the sorting which is used for grouping and explicit ORDER BY. is there any way to make the WHERE variant behave as in the second one? I doubt.

What version of MySQL?

In my opinion, the choice of an execution plan, as well as the preference of a particular plan, strongly depends on the selectivity of the index.
I tried to create a test table with a different number of duplicates and compared the execution plans and query performance on this table.
Results:
For low part of duplicates. In OP table 1500/300000=0.5%



Total rows
Duplicates
Join
In




15000
62 (0.4%)
0.01211000
0.02565750


15000
118
0.01559225
0.02836675


15000
133
0.01403475
0.02834625


15000
288
0.02084200
0.02859325


15000
1015
0.05302300
0.06872775


15000
1122
0.05069350
0.05169975


15000
2085
0.04678600
0.04377050


15000
3744
0.05224775
0.05224775



Plan for JOIN
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=12028 rows=14888) (actual time=10.8..11.7 rows=124 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on duplicate_names  (cost=3843..3950 rows=8410) (actual time=10.7..10.8 rows=62 loops=1)
        -> Materialize  (cost=3843..3843 rows=8410) (actual time=10.7..10.7 rows=62 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (count(0) > 1)  (cost=3002 rows=8410) (actual time=0.0488..10.7 rows=62 loops=1)
                -> Group aggregate: count(0)  (cost=3002 rows=8410) (actual time=0.045..9.72 rows=14938 loops=1)
                    -> Covering index scan on companies using ix_name  (cost=1513 rows=14888) (actual time=0.0379..4.67 rows=15000 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on companies using ix_name (name=duplicate_names.`name`)  (cost=0.443 rows=1.77) (actual time=0.014..0.0152 rows=2 loops=62)

For IN
-> Filter: <in_optimizer>(companies.`name`,companies.`name` in (select #2))  (cost=1513 rows=14888) (actual time=11.1..37.2 rows=124 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on companies  (cost=1513 rows=14888) (actual time=0.0463..6.53 rows=15000 loops=1)
    -> Select #2 (subquery in condition; run only once)
        -> Filter: ((companies.`name` = `<materialized_subquery>`.`name`))  (cost=3843..3843 rows=1) (actual time=0.00161..0.00161 rows=0.00827 loops=15001)
            -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=3843..3843 rows=1) (actual time=0.00146..0.00146 rows=0.00827 loops=15001)
                -> Index lookup on <materialized_subquery> using <auto_distinct_key> (name=companies.`name`)  (actual time=0.00132..0.00132 rows=0.00827 loops=15001)
                    -> Materialize with deduplication  (cost=3843..3843 rows=8410) (actual time=10.9..10.9 rows=62 loops=1)
                        -> Filter: (count(0) > 1)  (cost=3002 rows=8410) (actual time=0.0351..10.8 rows=62 loops=1)
                            -> Group aggregate: count(0)  (cost=3002 rows=8410) (actual time=0.0314..9.89 rows=14938 loops=1)
                                -> Covering index scan on companies using ix_name  (cost=1513 rows=14888) (actual time=0.0265..4.67 rows=15000 loops=1)

While duplicate names part is large, plan is different.
JOIN
EXPLAIN
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=13500 rows=5000) (actual time=10.5..31.4 rows=4972 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on companies  (cost=500 rows=5000) (actual time=0.0496..4.7 rows=5000 loops=1)
    -> Covering index lookup on duplicate_names using <auto_key0> (name=companies.`name`)  (cost=1001..1003 rows=10) (actual time=0.0046..0.00508 rows=0.994 loops=5000)
        -> Materialize  (cost=1000..1000 rows=1) (actual time=10.3..10.3 rows=967 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (count(0) > 1)  (cost=1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.0435..5.78 rows=967 loops=1)
                -> Group aggregate: count(0)  (cost=1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.0396..5.51 rows=995 loops=1)
                    -> Covering index scan on companies using ix_name  (cost=500 rows=5000) (actual time=0.0329..2.33 rows=5000 loops=1)

IN
EXPLAIN
-> Filter: <in_optimizer>(companies.`name`,companies.`name` in (select #2))  (cost=500 rows=5000) (actual time=8.01..28 rows=4972 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on companies  (cost=500 rows=5000) (actual time=0.0621..3.37 rows=5000 loops=1)
    -> Select #2 (subquery in condition; run only once)
        -> Filter: ((companies.`name` = `<materialized_subquery>`.`name`))  (cost=1000..1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.00407..0.00407 rows=0.994 loops=4994)
            -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=1000..1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.00313..0.00313 rows=0.994 loops=4994)
                -> Index lookup on <materialized_subquery> using <auto_distinct_key> (name=companies.`name`)  (actual time=0.0029..0.0029 rows=0.994 loops=4994)
                    -> Materialize with deduplication  (cost=1000..1000 rows=1) (actual time=7.79..7.79 rows=967 loops=1)
                        -> Filter: (count(0) > 1)  (cost=1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.107..7.02 rows=967 loops=1)
                            -> Group aggregate: count(0)  (cost=1000 rows=1) (actual time=0.103..6.82 rows=995 loops=1)
                                -> Covering index scan on companies using ix_name  (cost=500 rows=5000) (actual time=0.0936..3.33 rows=5000 loops=1)




Total rows
Duplicates
Join
In




10000
3125
0.05110900
0.03762375


5000
1816
0.02856050
0.02632475


5000
1794
0.08704400
0.02750950


5000
1862
0.06159625
0.03077825


5000
2844
0.06492925
0.03758150


5000
4003
0.05222750
0.05222750


5000
4007
0.06000325
0.04444525


5000
4007
0.04093250
0.03153725


5000
4004
0.02923175
0.04555700


5000
4005
0.04226600
0.03515675



The query execution time also depends on other factors, especially on such a small table of 5000 rows. But, nevertheless, the assumption that a particular execution plan is preferable to the selectivity of the data is confirmed.
Fiddle here
Test table
create table companies (id int primary key auto_increment
      , name  varchar(50) not null,Address varchar(100)
      ,LegalName varchar(100));
create index ix_name on companies (name);


It looks like subquery materialization would be more efficient for the 1st statement, but the optimizer chooses SUBQUERY execution strategy.
Are the statistics collected? If not, try collecting them: ANALYZE TABLE companies and re-running the 1st statement.
If you're on MySQL 8.0 or later you can use the optimizer hint:
SELECT *
FROM `companies`
WHERE `name` IN (
    SELECT /*+ SUBQUERY(MATERIALIZATION) */ `name`
    FROM `companies`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 1
);

